# Clarification : No simple group for order $5103 = 3^6 \cdot 7$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

No simple group for order $5103 = 3^6 \cdot 7$

using the small index argument and assuming the group is simple:

consider $n_{3}$ this must divide the rest of the order of the group and be congruent to $1$ modulo $3$ so $n_3 = 7$

Further there exists $\varphi : G \to S_{7}$ since $\mid G :  N_{G}(P_{3}) \mid \, = 7$ and $ker(\varphi)  \le N_{G}(P_{3})$ assuming this kernel is the identity we get $G \simeq S_{P} \le S_7$ hence $\mid G \mid$ $\displaystyle  \Bigg \vert \ \mid S_7\mid$

but the solution says $|G| \nmid 8!$ and I see that $n_3 \in \{1,7\}$ and $1+7 = 8$ so I see how they got $8$ but why $8$? aren't I supposed to be looking at $S_7$ and not $S_8$

EDIT: another group of order from the same question is for order $4125 = 5^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 11$, the solution uses $n_5 = 11$ from $n_5 \in \{ 1,3,11 \}$ but the uses $14!$ so now I am more confused at which $S_k$ how to decide what $K = ??$

Comment: I think your solution is fine: clearly $\;|G|\nmid 7!\;$ and that's the contradiction, so the Sylow $\;3-$ subgroup must be unique and thus normal.

Comment: @Joanpemo okay as long as it is still fine, could you maybe explain why they use 8 and then 14 in my secondary question

Comment: Also, if the Sylow $\;7$ - subgroup isn't normal then there are $\;3^6=729\;$ of them, which give $\;729\cdot6=4374\;$ elements of order 7, leaving $\;729\;$ elements which must thus be a unique Sylow $\;3$ - subgroup.

Comment: I really can't say. Is there any chance you're looking at the wrong questions' answers?

Comment: @Joanpemo haha I thought I was before I posted, had to do a few double takes but nope they are the correct questions

Comment: In what book are these exercises and these answers? It really looks odd unless they're using some other method.

Comment: @Joanpemo Dummit and Foote 6.2.6 and solutions are from a blog

Comment: Well, perhaps the blog is wrong...